# このサイトの下矢印の文字はどのようにすれば出てくるのでしょうか？

Tags: html, css, font

[このサイト](http://theme.nileforest.com/html/mazel-v1.4/01_mazel_multiprapose/home.html)を見て頂きたいのですが、メニューバーのHomeなどの横の下への矢印の文字があります。
HTML内では、`<i>`で囲まれていますが、その文字自体はHTMLコード内に存在していません。
これはどのようにして表示すればいいのでしょうか？
自分で使いたくて探してみたのですが見つかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コードを解析すればわかります。 http://theme.nileforest.com/html/mazel-v1.4/01_mazel_multiprapose/css/font-awesome.css Font Awesomeのサイトは[こちら](http://fontawesome.io/)。

Comment: WebiconとかWebfontの話でしょうか？

Comment: @oTak なるほど、そういうのを適応していたのですね。教えてくれてありがとうございます。

Comment: @Myaku Webicon、Webfontというのがあるのですね。教えてくれてありがとうございました。もっと調べてみます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)というアイコンに特化したCSSツールキットを使用しています。使い方はFont AwesomeのGet StartedやExampleを参考にしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。自分で試してみて、表示できました。